# MULTIPLICAR Y SUMAR

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo la siguiente tabla una columna con valores establecidos y otra columna con el resultado de la multiplicación de los valores, y abajo al termina la tabla tengo una celdas las cuales son la sumatoria de los resultados de las multiplicaciones ...lo he intentado de varias formas, sin embargo no obtengo el éxito con la sumatoria ..podrían ayudarme ...es j-query

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>Resultado</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Suma de Resultado</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Puedes incluir el codigo javascript que has estado usando, para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías ejecutar una función al cambiar el valor de cualquier input que recalcule la última celda de la fila y llame a recalcular la suma total.

Para la suma total bastaría con recorrer las filas con valor en la primera y última celdas y sumar el valor de la última.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo comentado en cada paso:

```js
$(function(){
  $('input').change(function(){
    // Tomamos el valor
    let value = parseInt($(this).val());
    // Seleccionamos la fila    
    let $fila = $(this).parents('tr');
    // Tomamos el valor de la primera celda
    let primera = parseInt($fila.find('td:first').text());
    // Calculamos la multiplicación
    let result = isNaN(value) ? ''
      : (value * primera);
    // Establecemos el contenido de la última celda
    $fila.find('td:last').text(result);
    // Recalculamos total
    recalcularTotal();
  });
  
  function recalcularTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    // Recorremos todas las filas
    $('tr').each(function(i, e){
      // Si la primera y última celdas tienen valor
      if ($(e).find('td:first').text()
            && $(e).find('td:last').text()){
        // Sumamos el valor de la última al total
        total += parseInt($(e).find('td:last').text());
      }
    });
    // Establecemos el valor de la celda resultado
    $('tr:last').find('td:last').text(total);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>Resultado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Suma de Resultado</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ya vi en donde esta mi problema de interpretación de selectores ..gracias saludos